# Upgrade Devel module and disable Kint

Tags: 9

When upgrading from Devel 8.x-2.x to Devel 8.x-4.x in a composer based build, how do I handle the Kint module being removed per [Remove Kint module and create a kint dumper plugin in devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel/issues/2839515)?

The service container can't be created because the Kint class is missing. I'll add the class path to Kint when I blow up the build again. :) Thank you.

Comment: Did you try upgrading from 2 to 3, and then 3 to 4?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Devel 4 you have to add Kint youself:

```bash
composer require drupal/devel kint-php/kint
```

You can read through this epic issue to learn more: [Unknown "kint" function. in Twig\ExpressionParser](https://gitlab.com/drupalspoons/devel/-/issues/320).

---

Also important to read the [release notes](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel/releases). On all 4.0.0+ releases the following is written. You have to do this **before upgrading**:

> If you have Kint module enabled, please run these commands before
> upgrading:
>
> 1. `drush pm:uninstall kint` or uninstall Kint using the Drupal UI
> 2. `composer require kint-php/kint`

---

To fix any Kint-missing-module-error, simply downgrade Devel `composer require 'drupal/devel:^2.1'`, uninstall Kint `drush pmu kint` and then upgrade again `composer require drupal/devel kint-php/kint`.

Comment: I've upgraded to `9` and updated `devel` before I uninstalled kint. I'm now stuck. When I try to enable other modules, I get this error: `Drupal\Core\Extension\Exception\UnknownExtensionException: The module kint does not exist.`

Comment: @AbdulSadikYalcin – Downgrade like described in the last section of my post. Or create a bare bone custom module with just an info file. web/modules/custom/kint/kint.info.yml. Fill the info file, see https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/let-drupal-know-about-your-module-with-an-infoyml-file. Then run `drush pmu kint`, done.

Comment: Downgrading is not an option unfortunately. Done too much work to risk losing. I'll try creating a dummy kint module and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I was including

```
// Change Kint maxLevels setting.
// @see https://gist.github.com/JPustkuchen/a5f1eaeb7058856b7ef087b028ffdfeb
include_once(DRUPAL_ROOT . '/modules/contrib/devel/kint/kint/Kint.class.php');
if (class_exists('Kint')) {
  Kint::$maxLevels = 6;
}
```

in settings.local.php. I recall reading somewhere that the default maxLevels in Kint is now 6 which makes the custom code snippet unnecessary. When I removed it, removed kint from core.extension.yml (in our case config_split.local) and added kint-php/kint via composer, all was well.

Thanks again @leymannx

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing the issue.
Use the development module **4.x-dev** 
If you are using the 4+ versions then use development version 4.x-dev .
https://www.drupal.org/project/devel

```
$ composer require drupal/devel:4.x-dev 
$ composer require kint-php/kint 
$ drush en -y devel
```

Enable Twig debugging it in development.services.yml file

```
twig.config:
    debug: true
    auto_reload: null
    cache: false
```

Goto /admin/config/development/devel and 
 set the "Variables dumper" to "Kint"

Add {{ kint() }} into template files.

Comment: Or just `composer require drupal/devel_kint_extras && drush -y en devel_kint_extras`. It gets the other dependencies automagically.

Comment: Thank you @leymannx